# how to pull wordpress post comments to a external page

Tags: theme-development, themes, comments

Hello I would like to know if there is a way to pull the contents of comments on a post to a separate page from wordpress. currently this is what i have, i'd like to replace with a function to pull the comments instead of pulling the link to the comments.

```
<?php
// Include Wordpress 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./blog/wp-load.php');
?>
<div>
<p style="font-size:18px;color:white;font-wieght:700;">Recently Asked Questions</p>
<?php query_posts('showposts=3'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<div id="faq">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a><br />
<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php comments_popup_link(); ?>
To see the answer to the question click <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">here</a>.<br /><br />
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add 
to your loop and replace it with the the_permalink() function something like this:

```
<?php
// Include Wordpress 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./blog/wp-load.php');
?>
<div>
<p style="font-size:18px;color:white;font-wieght:700;">Recently Asked Questions</p>
<?php query_posts('showposts=3'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<div id="faq">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a><br />
<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php comments_popup_link(); ?>
<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
<br />
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_comments()` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

```
<?php 
$comments = get_comments('post_id=15');
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo($comment->comment_author);
endforeach;
?>
```