# Where to insert get_comments?

Tags: comments

I'm trying to setup a page and extract comments from an external post. I took this advice [how to pull wordpress post comments to a external page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7919/how-to-pull-wordpress-post-comments-to-a-external-page/10560#10560) and now I have this get_comments code at my disposal:

```
<?php 
$comments = get_comments('post_id=15');
    foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo($comment->comment_author);
endforeach;
?>
```

Where on the page do I place this? Sorry for the noob question!

Comment: Well, where do you want comments to appear? How are you setting up page - custom page template?

Comment: Yes custom template and I can say that I've progressed since last week. Thanks for replying.

Comment: if you solved this by yourself please post this as an answer so others can benefit from it. If not (for any reason) and you no longer need answer to this specific question we can close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rarely use 'echo' in WordPress template themes because it can cause output to appear before the loops are even executed (aka, at the top of the page).

In this instance, I used the get_comments function within a function that hooked onto the content output:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'includePosts', 1);
```

Within the function includePosts, I have set $Comments to appear in the $content variable and I return $content just before adding the filter.

$content is used within the wp core function 'the_content' (includes/wp-page-template).

```
function the_content($more_link_text = null, $stripteaser = 0) {
$content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
}
```